# Get GCP (managed) instanced group's status

Tags: google-cloud-platform, autoscaling

How is the `Status` shown here for GCP managed instance group derived?

I don't see any such field in the [API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instanceGroupManagers/get). The console shows values like `Ready` and `Updating`, while the API only has `status.isStable`.

[image]

Comment: Look at the field `currentActions`.

Comment: Along with CurrentActions mentioned by John Hanley, You can also Refer this [Official Link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/getting-info-about-migs#verify_instances) to check the status of instances in a Managed Instance Group and Refer this [Official Link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/getting-info-about-migs#verify_group) to verify the status of MIG group level.

Comment: `currentActions` is a statuses to number of instances in those statuses, e.g. `creating: 1`, `deleting: 2`, etc. I guess it's summarized into a single `Status` on the UI via some unknown algorithm?

Comment: Seems to be Yes, it is summarized into a single status on the UI as As per this information in [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/getting-info-about-migs#verify_instances)

Answer (score 1):

Along with CurrentActions mentioned by John Hanley, You can also Refer this [Official Link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/getting-info-about-migs#verify_instances) to check the status of instances in a Managed Instance Group and Refer this [Official Link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/getting-info-about-migs#verify_group) to verify the status of MIG group level. [API DOC LINk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instanceGroupManagers/get)

Comment: Add a link to the API docs to your answer: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instanceGroupManagers/get